# Git- rebase conflicts after `git merge -X theirs develop`

Tags: git, github, merge

I am on branch `foo` and I want to merge `develop` into my feature branch `foo`. I want all conflicts to be automatically resolved and have any code in branch `foo` automatically over written. From branch `foo`, I do `git merge -X theirs develop` which works. When done twice to double check, I get `Already up-to-date`.

But then when I `git rebase develop` to make sure `foo` is caught up I get merge conflicts. Why is this when `git merge -X theirs develop` the merge should have all the updated `develop` code on branch `foo`?

Comment: If you've merged `develop` into `foo`, following up with `git rebase develop` "to make sure `foo` is caught up" makes no sense.  The whole point of doing such a merge is that it catches `foo` up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebase and merge do very different things.

When you run `git merge develop` you are telling Git to:

1. Identify the current commit (`HEAD`).  This has some hash ID.
2. Identify another commit, `develop`.  This has some hash ID.
3. Trace the commit graph to find the Lowest Common Ancestor *merge base* commit of the two commits identified in steps 1 and 2:

   ```
   ...--o--B--o--1   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
            \
             o--o--2   <-- develop
   ```
4. Compare (as in `git diff`) the merge base to commit #1.
5. Compare the merge base to commit #2.
6. Combine these two diffs.  (This combining step is where `-X theirs` makes a difference: if there are merge conflicts in the two diffs, Git prefers "their" change.  Note that for any part of a single file that shows two different but non-conflicting changes, Git still takes both changes.)  Apply the result to the tree in the merge base.
7. Make a new commit of type "merge commit", with parents #1 and #2 (in that order) on the current branch:

   ```
   ...--o--B--o--1---M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
            \       /
             o--o--2   <-- develop
   ```

If you now run the same `git merge` again, Git finds `M` and `2`, finds their merge base (which is not `B` this time but `2`), and declares that there is nothing to do: the merge base is already one of the two commits.

When you run `git rebase develop` you are telling Git to:

1. Make a list of all commits reachable from the current branch tip (`M`, after this merge is done) that are *not* reachable from the commit identified by `develop` (commit #2):

   ```
   ...--o--B--o*-1*--M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
            \       /
             o--o--2   <-- develop
   ```

   I marked these commits with `*`.  Note: `M` is also reachable from `M` but not from `2`; but `git rebase` deliberately throws away all merges, as it does not make sense to try to rebase a merge.
2. Using "detached HEAD" mode, *copy* (see below) the marked commits, placing the new copies after the commit identified by the name `develop`:

   ```
   ...--o--B--o*-1*--M   <-- somebranch
            \       /
             o--o--2   <-- develop
                    \
                     o*'--1*'   <-- HEAD
   ```
3. After all copies successfully made (including resolving any merge conflicts), *remove* the `somebranch` label from wherever it is now and place it at the end of the copied commits:

   ```
   ...--o--B--o--1---M   [abandoned]
            \       /
             o--o--2   <-- develop
                    \
                     o'--1'   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
   ```

To copy a commit, Git essentially (and sometimes literally) runs `git cherry-pick` on it.  The cherry-pick operation is itself the "verb kind" of merging (with a somewhat peculiar merge base, and "ours" and "theirs" can be confusing as well—see comments).  Thus, each of these copies, for however many commits are to be copied, can have merge conflicts.  Any resolutions you made in `M` are ignored (naturally, since `M` is itself ignored).

Comment: Would it be helpful to point out explicitly that the copying rebase does is itself a merge, using the rebased commit's parent as the merge base, the rebased commit as the "theirs" tip, and the new base as the "ours" tip?

Comment: @jthill: possibly ... I get some pushback on overly long answer sometimes, so I wonder :-)